# How to find entity with relationship table SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a API for a Delivery. So I have Dish, Order and DishOrder entitys, I'm saving the orders, but when I try to find the orders spring gave me this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not extract ResultSet (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.XYZ.model.entity.Order["orderDish"])]
```

My code is more or less like this:

Order:

```java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<OrderDish> orderDishes;
```

Dish:

```java
@OneToMany
@JsonIgnore
private List<OrderDish> orderDishes;
```

OrderDish:

```java
@EmbeddedId
@JsonIgnore
private OrderDishId id;
```

OderDishId:

```java
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_dish", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Dish dish;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_dish", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Order order;
```

Comment: its looking for "dishOrder" but you have "orderDish"?

Comment: I edited, I've commit some mistakes translating.